# "Was of Libyan descent?"

Tags: grammar

I got confused when I was reading this sentence.

He ***was of Libyan descent*** and investigators say he recently spent three weeks in Libya.

Why does this sentence use "was of" and not just "was"?

Thanks.

Comment: In addition to what the 2 answers say, dropping *of* to produce "He was ( * ) Libyan descent" makes the person out to be some kind of *descent* (whatever that means), which isn't what the original says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one were to say *he was Libyan* then it would be understood that this person was a Libyan national, either born in Libya or otherwise a person who became a Libyan citizen at some point.

Instead, as stated, to say *he was of Libyan descent* means that this person is not necessarily (the presumption would be he is not) a Libyan national or Libyan citizen, but instead his connection to Libya is through his [hereditary lineage](http://grammarist.com/spelling/decent-descent/) - perhaps some or all of his parents or grandparents were Libyan.

Perhaps this phrase would be more understandable to you if you substituted some words and considered:

- he was of a Libyan hereditary lineage
- he was of a hereditary lineage that originated in Libya

Answer (score 1):

`To be + of + [adjective] + descent` simply means "to have the origins described by the said adjective."

Thus, if he was of Libyan descent, his ancestors came from Libya.

Comment: Upvoted - good answer, although you might have been more clear around what you meant by *his origin was Libyan* - I think this phrase means more precisely that some of his *ancestors' origins were Libyan* not that he necessarily originated there.

Comment: @Brillig If you have a less confusing way in which I might formulate that, please let me know. I'm always open to suggestions.

Comment: That does it I think!  Nice edit!